# how to get specific character from a log file in linux

Tags: linux, text-processing

have a log file , having multiple contents inside the file like and example below is the content of U123.log . I have n number of logs..

```
Accepted password for hoover from 10.0.2.2 port 4792 ss

Id : UN123P 

ID_MTCH : UnixProduction

Accepted password for hoover from 10.0.2.2 port 4792 ss

Accepted password for hoover from 10.0.2.2 port 4792 ss
```

Is there any we can fetch `Id : UN123P` & `ID_MTCH` from each log as an output of linux command. We have some 1000's of logs and from all the logs , trying to fetch the value only starts with  `ID :` & `ID_MTCH` and sample output as below

```
Id : UN123P 

ID_MTCH : UnixProduction
```

Pls suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `grep` for that

`grep -i -E 'ID|ID_MTCH' *.log`

Comment: Thanks Lawrence for the reply , i missed to add a point in the query , I just modified my question now

Comment: @Arya Updated my answer to match

Answer (score 1):

Depending on whether the pattern can also occur later in log lines (and not only at the beginning), you may have to use anchored regular expression with `grep`, as in

```
grep '^\(Id\|ID_MTCH\)' *.log
```

or

```
grep -E '^(Id|ID_MTCH)' *.log
```

This will then only match lines that *begin* (as first character, without leading space etc.!) with the pattern mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

`man grep` says

```
 grep  searches  for PATTERNS in each FILE.  PATTERNS is one or patterns
       separated by newline characters, and grep prints each line that matches
       a pattern.

 grep [OPTION...] PATTERNS [FILE...]

 -i, --ignore-case
              Ignore case distinctions, so that characters that differ only in
              case match each other.
```

Use the following code

```
grep -i ID *.log
```

`-i` is important as it makes the grepping independent of case.

Answer (score 0):

To match both cases, you can use extended grep (egrep) as well. This works the same way as grep -E would.

```
egrep -i -r '^Id|^id_match' *.log
```